# Why I can't to change bk color of CStatusBarCtrl when change the version of ComCtrl?

Tags: mfc

I want to change face of old MFC App for that I try to change version of Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls
by add this lines to one of files in project

```
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

but now CStatusBarCtrl::SetBkColor don't work for me
how I can to fix

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **SB_SETBKCOLOR** works only if visual styles are turned off. So you need to disable visual theme in order to make it work.

I'd suggest subclassing the status bar and handle WM_PAINT in order to customize the visual appearance.

Comment: or I can turn of theme for CtatusBarCtrl by SetWindowTheme(status_bar->m_hWnd, L" ", L" ");

Comment: are there other massages that don't work with visual styles? where can I to find list of these messages?